# what is the difference between using escape sequences and using "SetConsoleTextAttribute" function to color the text in terminal using c?

Tags: c, terminal, colors, console

I was searching for a method to color my c program text, and I found two ways:

1- Using escape sequences in the form `\033[1;<color code>m`
2- Using SetConsoleTextAttribute() function

I want to know what is the difference between the two ?
and when should I use one or the other ?

Comment: ANSI escape sequences are vestiges of ancient VT-100 terminals, carried forward to almost equally ancient DOS consoles.  In "modern times", you'll probably use them mostly with Windows "cmd" consoles.  Not all console-mode apps support ANSI escape sequences. If you're programming in a language that can make Win32 calls like SetConsoleTextAttribute(), then that's generally the preferred approach.

Comment: @paulsm4, ANSI escape sequences work on a wide variety terminal-like interfaces, on multiple platforms.  Win32 functions, on the other hand, work only on Windows.

Comment: Yes,  And if the OP is using SetConsoleTextAttribute(), then obviously Win32 is at least an option.   For PowerShell scripts, I'd prefer `Write-Host --ForegroundColor ...``.  For most Windows-centric use cases, I'd discourage ANSI escape codes.  For cross-platform text control (including cursor control, text colors, etc.) I'd encourage [ncurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).  Even though they've been around "forever", in general, ANSI codes are a poor choice...